# How find text programmatically?

Tags: android, search, text, find, searchview

Is there any way to find the text programmatically? 
I would like put a extensive text in a TextView or other way, and then to search for specific words, as if you used Ctrl + F. I don't found information, I found SearchView but these search data only of a View, no?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can make it by yourself. Get the text of textview, then find your text based on search bar using your own search algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the method .contains provided by the String class that "Returns true if and only if this string contains the specified sequence of char values" (Oracle Docs) within your algorithm for searching for text then based on what that method returns execute certain code to do what you want if the CharSequence exists or not.

[String Class (Oracle)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: You know any example or tutorial on how to do it? I don't found anything google. Thank You

Comment: This may help (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831163/check-if-edittext-has-specific-character), using a `TextWatcher` sounds like a good idea but other wise I don't have any tutorials or examples on this to help, sorry. There must be a way to this since it is extremely likely someone has tried to do this before. Hope you find a solution!